# Strange behavior in Firefox when nextSibling is a comment

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I am pushing nextSiblings into an array inside a while loop. I know Firefoxe is different from IE in the way it picks up nextSibling (it treats whitespace and carriage returns as nodes). But when it picked up regular html comments it goes into an infinite loop, like there are infinite nextSibling nodes that are comments. The solution was simple after I figured out what was happening (just check for nodetype and not push it into array if it's a comment) but I'm really curious if anyone else experienced this and why this is happening?  Thanks you.

Comment: Just for the record: From the xml/xslt perspective, the difference you describe in your second sentence is odd and unexpected behavior in IE. (I second Ken's request for an example.)

Comment: the while loop that is causing the problem looks like this while (thisNode.nextSibling && thisNode.nextSibling.nodeName !== thisNode.nodeName) { console.log(thisNode.nextSibling.nodeType +" "+thisNode.nextSibling); elementarray.append($(thisNode.nextSibling)); }

Comment: basically grab the first node and store everything until you find another node of the same name, so if the markup looks like this:

<h3>title</h3> <h2>content title</h2> <div>my content</div>

<h3>title 2</h3> <h2>content title 2</h2> <div>my content 2</div>

<h2>content title</h2> and <div>my content</div> will get stored in elementarray. But if I have a comment in the markup what I see in the console is "8 [object Comment]" so FF returns comment node name as 8 but it just goes into an infinite loop and the browser throws up an error saying the script is too slow.

Comment: your while loop is not iterating. `thisNode` always refer to the same node and never changes.